# Проблема с адаптивом слайдера

Tags: javascript, frontend

Всем привет , я совсем новичок в js, и вот какая проблема у меня возникла:
При изменении ширины экрана слайды начинают работать неккоректно , это происходит из-за того, что переменная, которой присвоено значение ширины слайдера остается неизменной при уменьшении / увелечении окна браузера, она получает корректное значение только при перезагрузке. Я пробовал отслеживать ширину экрана путем запуска requestAnimationFrame , но присвоив значение (которое обновлялось при уменьшении / увелечении) переменной, она получала значение при старте функции, а точнее Null, затем я начал искать что либо о динамических переменных, но решил что не буду изобретать велосипед и лучше спрошу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отслеживать ширину окна браузера можете использовать следующий код:

```
document.addEventListener('resize' , () => {

  //тут пишете код, который должен регулировать ширину ваших слайдов
})
```

Comment: Благодарю, вы очень мне помогли

Comment: Учтите, что на мобильном сафари после переворота экрана `resize` может отдать неправильные значения.